# Regex split TitleCase Word

Tags: php, regex, pcre

My regex doesn't really work for splitting a TitleCase word in PHP.
Articles without an author should not be affected by the regex.

**My current regex:** `From (\S+\s){2}(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])`

Here is my [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/00Wyol/1)

**Input:**

`From Günther RossmannThis is the article
From Harry Gregson-WilliamsAnother article text
From Nora WaldstättenSome lorem ipsum stuff
From the fantastic architect of the year
Text without an author`

**Expected output:**

`<b>From Günther Rossman</b> This is the article
<br>From Harry Gregson-Williams</b> Another article text
<br>From Nora Waldstätten</b> Some lorem ipsum stuff
From the fantastic architect of the year
Text without an author`

Comment: There is no second whitespace after the lowercase letter. You might use a "quick fix" like [`From (\S+\s\S+)(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])`](https://regex101.com/r/ppJmFa/1/) or try a solution like [`'~From\s+(\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*\s+\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*)~u'`](https://regex101.com/r/ppJmFa/3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `{2}` quantifier your pattern gets expanded as `\S+\s\S+\s` but there is no whitespace between the lower- and the uppercase letter.

You may use

```
'~From\s+(\S+\s\S+)(?![^\p{Lu}])~u'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ccnELf/2)

**Details**

- `From` - a literal substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\S+\s\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars, 1 whitespace and again 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `(?![^\p{Lu}])` - followed with an uppercase letter or end of string.

Or, use a more specific one:

```
'~From\s+(\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*\s+\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*)~u'
```

Or, to also support apostrophes or hyphens:

```
From\h+(\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*(?:[\h-']\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*)*)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ppJmFa/5). Here, `\p{Lu}` matches an uppercase letter, `\p{Ll}*` matches 0+ lowercase letters.

Note that for easier access, you may even get rid of the capturing group and use `\K` operator that omits the text matched so far from the match value:

```
'~From\h+\K\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*(?:[\h-']\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*)*~u'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ppJmFa/6).

Note that you should use `u` modifier when using Unicode property classes like `\p{Lu}` and Unicode strings.

Comment: Just one thing: "Harry Gregson-Williams" - your second and third regex doesn't match it...

Comment: @sinisake The [first one](https://regex101.com/r/ccnELf/3) does. Actually, I added an enhanced version for both Version 2 and 3. Now, they will also match `From Günther O'Reily`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex to match title case author names preceded by `From`:

```
\bFrom(?:[\h-]+\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*)+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WNOUL3/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\bFrom`: Match `From` with word boundary
- `(?:`: Start non-capturing group

  - `[\h-]+`: Match `1+` horizontal space or hyphen
  - `\p{Lu}`: Match `1` uppercase unicode letters
  - `\p{Ll}*`: Match `0` or more lower case unicode letters
- `)+`: End non-capturing group. Match `1` or more of this group

Comment: This, Some and Another should be author's name?

Comment: Thanks @sinisake, I have fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/HylfCl/1)

```
(From \S+\h+\S+(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu}))
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
From Günther RossmannThis is the article
From Harry Gregson-WilliamsAnother article text
From Nora WaldstättenSome lorem ipsum stuff
From the fantastic architect of the year
Text without an author
```

#### Output

```
<b>From Günther Rossmann</b>This is the article
<b>From Harry Gregson-Williams</b>Another article text
<b>From Nora Waldstätten</b>Some lorem ipsum stuff
From the fantastic architect of the year
Text without an author
```

---

### Explanation

- `(From \S+\h+\S+(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu}))` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `From` Match this literally
  - `\S+` Match any non-whitespace character one or more times
  - `\h+` Match any horizontal whitespace character one or more times
  - `\S+` Match any non-whitespace character one or more times
  - `(?<=\p{Ll})` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is a lowercase character in any language/script (Unicode)
  - `(?=\p{Lu})` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is an uppercase character in any language/script (Unicode)

I use `\p{}` character classes to ensure any script is matched; since you have two names with Unicode symbols in them.